# cleaning up proof that Thomae's function is not $BV([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to clean up the following proof, there are a few technical details which I wish to iron out.

**Question**: Does the following proof work out?

I want to show that Thomae's function with $f=\begin{cases} 0, x\in [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q} \\ \frac{1}{q}, \ for \ x=\frac{p}{q} \ ,x\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

does not have bounded variation on $[0,1]$

Recall all functions which have bounded variation can be decomposed as a difference of two monotone increasing functions. Consider the standard Jordan Decomposition:

$f=f^{+}-f^{-}$. Define a function $V:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $V(x)=V_f(0,x)$, and note $V$ is monotone increasing on $[0,1]$ if $f$ is of bounded variation. Also, we have that $V-f$ is a monotone increasing function on $[0,1]$ (again, if $f$ is of bounded variation).

Note we have $f=V-(V-f)$.

For $V_f(0,x)$, we see the variation is not finite. Let $x\in (a,b)\subset (0,1)$. We are guaranteed by density to find a rational and irrational in that interval. Let $r$ be the rational and $y$ be the irrational. The variation $V_f(0,y)>\frac{1}{q}$ (since the function jumps by $1/q$ when we go from rational to irrational). However, we can consider a sequence of shrinking intervals $(\frac{a}{n},\frac{b}{n})$. In each interval, we have a variation of $V_f(0,y_n)>\frac{1}{q}$, and if we consider the variation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(r)-f(y)|\geq\frac{1}{q}$ and if we take $n\rightarrow \infty$ (shrink the intervals to arbitrarily small length), then we have a harmonic-like series
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}=k(\frac{1}{q})$ (for each sub-interval, we add the variation, which is at least $\frac{1}{q}$), and so the series diverges, so $V_f(0,x)$ is not finite, so Thomae's function is not $BV([0,1])$

I could have use the definition of $BV$ directly and not bothered with Jordan decomposition, but I wanted to show the proof in two *"almost"* different ways.

Comment: What is the question? (By the way, Thomae's function is a bit different in that $q$ is the denominator of $x$ rather than a fixed constant. And I think you are missing a summand in the harmonic-like series.)

Comment: yes, you are right, I edited the question. For the harmonic like series, I was not being as diligent with keeping track of constants. That said, looking back through the argument, I am not seeing any constants I missed!

Comment: "For $V_f(0,x)$, we see the variation is not finite." That's an odd thing to say. Isn't that what you are proving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the point of the Jordan decomposition here; it only serves to complicate things as far as I can see.

This might be cleaner: Let $x_n = 1/n, n=1,2,\dots.$ Then for each $n,$ there is an irrational $y_n \in (x_{n+1},x_n)^*.$ Our sequences are then ordered like this: $x_1 > y_1 > x_2>y_2 > x_3 > \cdots.$ Since $f(x_n) = 1/n, f(y_n)=0,$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}(f(x_n)-f(y_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}$$

for any finte $N.$ The last sum $\to\infty$ as $N\to \infty,$ and thus $f\notin BV([0,1]).$

$^*$ For example we could choose $y_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\dfrac{1}{n+1} + \left (1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right )\dfrac{1}{n}.$